# How to fetch records from 2 tables with with where from on ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenerio whom i need to fetch the records from 2 tables based on one userID.
suppose if my id is 31, so i want to fetch the records of ID 31 from both tables.
I have tried many solutions but none work for me. please have a look and help me out.

the table structure of video table:

```
CREATE TABLE `web_videos` (
  `vID` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `v_filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v_uploadname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `v_short_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `v_singerName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `v_approve` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `v_price` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`vID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

the table structure of audio table:

```
CREATE TABLE `web_audio` (
  `aID` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `a_filename` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `a_uploadname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `a_genre` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `a_singerName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `a_approve` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `a_price` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`aID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

my record set i am getting is:

```
3   31  test    mohsin_781.mp3  3   test singer 0   2.50    2   31  asd _639.flv     asdasdd    asd sadasd  0   6.33
4   31  asd mohsin_180.mp3  10  asd 0   7.34    2   31  asd _639.flv     asdasdd    asd sadasd  0   6.33
5   31  mn  _977.mp3    5   lkj 0   8.77    2   31  asd _639.flv     asdasdd    asd sadasd  0   6.33
3   31  test    mohsin_781.mp3  3   test singer 0   2.50    3   31  asdasd  _922.flv    ad asdada da das    adsad   0   6.33
4   31  asd mohsin_180.mp3  10  asd 0   7.34    3   31  asdasd  _922.flv    ad asdada da das    adsad   0   6.33
5   31  mn  _977.mp3    5   lkj 0   8.77    3   31  asdasd  _922.flv    ad asdada da das    adsad   0   6.33
3   31  test    mohsin_781.mp3  3   test singer 0   2.50    4   31  fdgdfg  _745.flv    fdgfdgfdgg dfgdf gd gdf gdf gdf dfg fgd dgdfg   gdfg    0   88.55
4   31  asd mohsin_180.mp3  10  asd 0   7.34    4   31  fdgdfg  _745.flv    fdgfdgfdgg dfgdf gd gdf gdf gdf dfg fgd dgdfg   gdfg    0   88.55
5   31  mn  _977.mp3    5   lkj 0   8.77    4   31  fdgdfg  _745.flv    fdgfdgfdgg dfgdf gd gdf gdf gdf dfg fgd dgdfg   gdfg    0   88.55
```

MY SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT
web_audio.aID,
web_audio.userID,
web_audio.a_filename,
web_audio.a_uploadname,
web_audio.a_genre,
web_audio.a_singerName,
web_audio.a_approve,
web_audio.a_price
FROM
web_audio
INNER JOIN web_videos ON web_videos.userID = web_audio.userID
WHERE
web_audio.userID = 31 AND web_videos.userID = 31
```

you can see its duplicating the records. so please make it  like i have only records with userID 31 without duplication.

thank you please.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct web_audio.aID,
web_audio.userID,
web_audio.a_filename,
web_audio.a_uploadname,
web_audio.a_genre,
web_audio.a_singerName,
web_audio.a_approve,
web_audio.a_price 
FROM web_audio
INNER JOIN web_videos ON web_videos.userID = web_audio.userID
WHERE
web_audio.userID = 31 AND web_videos.userID = 31
```

use distinct to avoid duplication.

Comment: please fetch the records of video table as well against the same 31 id. it duplicates

Comment: [try this link](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/ms-sql/threads/186025/removing-duplicates-from-inner-join-of-two-tables) same problem trick is discussed @user3040719

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT web_audio.*
FROM web_audio INNER JOIN 
web_videos ON web_videos.userID = web_audio.userID
WHERE
web_audio.userID = 31 AND web_videos.userID = 31
GROUP BY web_audio.aid
```

See example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9d5b/12).

Since you are selecting values only from `web_audio`, use this:

```
SELECT * FROM web_audio WHERE userID=31
```

Both of them will give same result.

Comment: please fetch the records of video table as well against the same 31 id. it duplicates

Comment: can you show some sample data or provide a template in sql fiddle, please?

Comment: @user3040719: Edited my answer. See the example in fiddle. If that is not your required result, please update your question with the required result.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
DISTINCT web_audio.aID,
 --the rest of yout query
```

Comment: please fetch the records of video table as well against the same 31 id. it duplicates

Comment: [Err] 1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that v_shortdesc and a_genre have different data types, because for UNION to work, you must have the same data type for each column.

Comment: I've tested the query with DISTINCT, and it gives me three rows with no duplicate, isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: dear Sir, we want to fetch video records as well. that are 3.

Comment: you can see i have videos too with the same ID 31. i need this one too. hope you do not mind. thank you